# Want to add pictures to a JPanel on click of a Button

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jdialog

I have to create a program where I will display some options to a user on a Dialog box to choose.
Based on the option chosen by the user, I have to display that picture in another dialog which was empty before.

Example :

- Both dialog "one" and "two" are visible to user. Dialog "one" has many buttons displayed on it. Where as Dialog "two" is empty.
- user click on button A available on Dialog "one", then I have to show that picture on Dialog "two".
- user click on a different button B available on Dialog "one", then I have to show that picture on Dialog "two" along with the older picture.

Can this be done dynamically without creating a new Dialog "two" or without creating a new JPanel for Dialog "two".

SO far I have created below program but it does not add the picture after it ran.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalIconFactory.FolderIcon16;


public class Launcher {

    JDialog keyboardDialog;
    JDialog nameViewDialog;
    JPanel nameViewJPanel;
    JDialog FinalNameViewDialog;

    private final transient ActionListener keyButtonListener =
        new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
               System.out.println( ((JButton) event.getSource()).getActionCommand());
               String buttonType=((JButton) event.getSource()).getActionCommand();
               ImageIcon iconA = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("\\Icons\\A1.PNG"));
               JLabel la=new JLabel(iconA);
               nameViewJPanel.add(la);
               nameViewJPanel.repaint();
            }
        };

    public Launcher()
    {
        nameViewDialog=new JDialog();
        nameViewDialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        nameViewJPanel=new JPanel();
        nameViewJPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
        nameViewDialog.setSize(430, 490);

         ImageIcon iconA1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("\\Icons\\A1.PNG"));
         JLabel la=new JLabel(iconA1);
         nameViewJPanel.add(la);
         ImageIcon iconA2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("\\Icons\\B1.PNG"));
         JLabel lb=new JLabel(iconA2);
         nameViewJPanel.add(lb);
         nameViewDialog.add(nameViewJPanel);

        keyboardDialog=new JDialog(nameViewDialog,ModalityType.MODELESS);
        keyboardDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(nameViewDialog);

        keyboardDialog.setSize(230,190);
        keyboardDialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
        ImageIcon iconA = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("\\JaLetters\\A.PNG"));
        ImageIcon iconB = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("\\JaLetters\\B.PNG"));
        ImageIcon iconC = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("\\JaLetters\\C.PNG"));
        ImageIcon iconD = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("\\JaLetters\\D.PNG"));
        ImageIcon iconE = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("\\JaLetters\\E.PNG"));
        ImageIcon iconF = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("\\JaLetters\\F.PNG"));

        JButton ba=new JButton();
        ba.setIcon(iconA);
        ba.setActionCommand("A");
        ba.addActionListener(keyButtonListener);

        JButton bb=new JButton();
        bb.setIcon(iconB);
        bb.setActionCommand("B");
        bb.addActionListener(keyButtonListener);

        JButton bc=new JButton();
        bc.setIcon(iconC);
        bc.setActionCommand("C");
        bc.addActionListener(keyButtonListener);

        JButton bd=new JButton();
        bd.setIcon(iconD);
        bd.setActionCommand("D");
        bd.addActionListener(keyButtonListener);

        JButton be=new JButton();
        be.setIcon(iconE);
        be.setActionCommand("E");
        be.addActionListener(keyButtonListener);

        JButton bf=new JButton();
        bf.setIcon(iconF);
        bf.setActionCommand("F");
        bf.addActionListener(keyButtonListener);

        keyboardDialog.add(ba);
        keyboardDialog.add(bb);
        keyboardDialog.add(bc);
        keyboardDialog.add(bd);
        keyboardDialog.add(be);
        keyboardDialog.add(bf);

        nameViewDialog.setVisible(true);
        keyboardDialog.setVisible(true);


    }


public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Launcher();
}

}
```

Comment: This screams model and [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html). I'd be hesitant to do this using two dialogs however, preferringng perhaps to use to panels in a `JSplitPane` or using the second dialog as a popup to gather informaiton which, when closed, allows the first window to update itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a CustomJPanel to the Dialog two. Each actionlistener loads an different image and sends it to the CustomJPanel which draws the image.

Here is MVC of it:

**Main class:**

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setSize(600, 400);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        CustomJPanel customJDialog = new CustomJPanel();
        dialog.add(customJDialog);

        JDialog dialog2 = new JDialog();
        dialog2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        dialog2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog2.setLocationRelativeTo(dialog);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Image 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Image 2");

        dialog2.add(button1);
        dialog2.add(button2);

        dialog2.pack();
        dialog2.setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            BufferedImage image = null;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("test1.jpg"));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                customJDialog.setImage(image);
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            BufferedImage image = null;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("test2.jpg"));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                customJDialog.setImage(image);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**CustomJPanel**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CustomJPanel extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage image = null;

    public CustomJPanel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
        System.out.println(image);
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any mechanism you know which can repaint the window with the new picture but still keep the older picture on CustomPanel. Your answer works for me but I need to keep the older picture also on screen

Comment: I could change your program to store all the pictures in a list and repaint the window everytime using the list by drawing all pictures in a loop. But I am looking if there is any other efficient way available in which I dont need to draw all the pictures, rather I should draw only the last picture and older picture stay as it as.

Comment: @HimJEL I can't think of other way but to add CustomJPanel for each for each image in a list and than add them and remove from dialog. (also you can do this with other components like JLabel, doesn't need to be an JPanel) But i guess this doesn't suit you as you said it the question. What kind of optimization are you limited to?